# Sending a http response through a custom attribute in dotnet

Tags: c#, .net, custom-attributes

I'm creating a custom attribute in dotnet that is supposed to check the authorization header. If it is the same as some hard coded string it is supposed to pass but else the user should not be able to use the specified route.

I think I'm getting the response header correctly but I'm not sure how to send a HTTP response if it fails.

```
  public class CustomAuthorization : ActionFilterAttribute
  {
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
              var httpContext = context.HttpContext;
              string authHeader = httpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

         if(authHeader == "Kawaii") 
         {
             return;
             //do nothing cause its fine
         }
         else
         {
             httpContext.Response.WriteAsync("The authorization header was incorrect, is should be Kawaii");    
         }
     }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's awkward to first let request through and check auth *after* request is finished... Can you please clarify why you decided to do that?

Comment: I didn't know that's what I was doing at the time. It's not supposed to do that.

Answer (score 2):

From what you've described, it sounds like you should be using `OnActionExecuting` instead of `OnActionExecuted`. Within the body, instead of writing to `context.HttpContext.Response`, you set `context.Result` to an ActionResult representing the response

```
public class CustomAuthorization : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        string authHeader = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

        if(authHeader == "Kawaii")
            return;

        context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
    }
}
```

However, this approach sounds like a better fit for an *AuthorizationFilter* instead of an *ActionFilter*. Have a look at the [filter pipeline documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for a list of the different types of filters and what they do.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try this out and post an update.